# Карточки слайдера slick

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Такая проблема, верстаю карусель из карточек, используя slick. Сам слайдер работает, но я хочу, чтобы карточки меняли резиново свои размеры (ширина, высота, font-size) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как правильно это сделать. В чем грамотнее задавать размеры? Жестко в px? Или в em? Как быть с размером текста, чтобы он не вылезал за пределы карточки... Честно, уже запутался сильно. Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

картинкам можно задать ширину в таких единицах измерения как (vmin) и при этом aspect-ratio: 9/16 - например,
а текст (поиграть с calc()):

```
font-size: calc(.5em + 2vw)
```

в таком роде подбирать…